# How to fetch latest 100 rows (inserted or updated) from Oracle table?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, sql-limit

How to fetch latest 100 rows (inserted or updated) from Oracle table ?
Need queries for below situations -
1.Table does not have any date column.
2.Table has date column.

The query should work in Oracle 11g  and later on in Oracle 12c.

Answer (score 1):

Your table should have enabled `rowdependencies` option  and fetch by ora_rowscn pseudocolumn:

```
Select * from t order by ora_rowscn desc fetch first 100 rows only
```

If your table has no rowdependencies option, you need to recreate it with rowdependencies

Comment: Read more about ora_rowscn: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/pseudocolumns007.htm

Comment: That (FETCH clause) won't work on 11g, Sayan. Also, it "... is useful for determining approximately when a row was last updated. It is not absolutely precise" so ... yes, maybe your idea would work for the OP. Can't tell. But - thanks for pointing that out, didn't think of ORA_ROWSCN pseudocolumn **at all**.

Comment: I think I need to downvote, but would loved to be convinced otherwise.  `ORA_ROWSCN` is unreliable for this.  E.g., Update row "A" at 10am, Update 100 other rows at 11am.  Someone queries the block containing row "A" at 12 noon.  If that block is cleaned out as part of the query, it will get an `ORA_ROWSCN` later than the 100 other rows that were updated later.  I.e., you will NOT get the last 100 rows in your results.  Your process will seem to work, especially on small tables with small transactions, but will be unreliable.

Comment: @MatthewMcPeak - why would a query modify the `ORA_ROWSCN` value? And are you confusing coarse (referring to blocks) and fine-grained (referring to row)? If another row in the same block as "A" is modified later, with `rowdependencies` set that shouldn't affect "A" or the rest of the block, should it? (Compare [this](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=4fc33edb54bb6f05cbe1c06c4ead1a08) with [this](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=61837aaf881b27738f415a1d3ebefb65)). I'm also not 100% sure about relying on it but it ought to work, I think.

Comment: @AlexPoole Delayed block cleanout.  If I update a billion rows in a table, the commit still happens instantly and atomically.  The blocks containing those billion rows may have been flushed by DBWR and even aged out of the block cache prior to your commit.  If so, they will largely not be cleaned out until they are queried (possibly much later by another session).  This, I believe, can cause the ORA_ROWSCN to be changed.

Comment: Right... so I was misreading your first comment, and wasn't aware of that effect anyway.  Thanks. Still, I was right not be be 100% sure about relying on it *8-) (And also as the linked doc says, "If a block is queried twice, then it is possible for the value of ORA_ROWSCN to change between the queries even though rows have not been updated in the time between the queries." so even that effectively says you can't rely on it.)

Comment: There is no "dirty reads" in Oracle. And it doesn't matter what exactly is on the disk. Read more about read consistency

Comment: @SayanMalakshinov I think I am entitled to downvote as long as I own it and explain my objections.  Read the documentation on `ORA_ROWSCN` and see how Oracle goes out of their way to explain what is and is not guaranteed as far as the accuracy.  If I get time later, I will try to demonstrate a failure, but it is difficult to cause Oracle to do a delayed block cleanout in my instance, since the buffer pools are so large.  Nevertheless, if I am unable to illustrate a failure, I will reverse my downvote but keep my comments.  Fair?

Comment: @MatthewMcPeak be sure, your downvote doesn't bother me, I more wonder why people don't read and check own hypotheses. It's really pretty easy to check: create table with several rows and enabled rowdependencies, update few rows but don't commit, read the table with ora_rowscn using serial direct path reads in another session (use `table_stats()` hint to force direct reads) - it will force object checkpoint and flush dirty block to disk, then dump the table block and compare ora_rowscn in the block with ora_rowscn returned from the query - you will see that your query returns consistent rowscn

Comment: @MatthewMcPeak I can do such a test case easily for you, but I think since you don't trust my words above, you will not trust my output too. And anyway, I believe that if you check it yourself, it will give you better experience. Just don't confuse people without simple checking your own delusions.

Comment: @SayanMalakshinov One can do a hundred test cases in which your solution works.  Nevertheless, it is unreliable when there are delayed block cleanouts.  Since you cited Oracle Core by Jonathan Lewis, I will refer you to this discussion: https://jonathanlewis.wordpress.com/2010/09/03/last-modified/.  See comment #5 by JL: "in the case the block would have been written to disc before the commit took place... when the cleanout takes place Oracle... will only work out an 'upper bound commit'. This may be an SCN that is much later than the actual commit SCN of the txn"

Comment: @MatthewMcPeak but it's easier for you - you need just 1 test case to disprove my words: it's pretty easy to create a test case as you said in your first comment here. Note that DSCN values are restored for read consistency as other row data, you can find it in redo and undo

Comment: + if that is not reliable enough for you, what would you suggest more reliable?

Comment: @SayanMalakshinov Did you even read the link I posted?  There is Jonathan Lewis explaining the exact same thing I downvoted for: when a row is updated at SCN X and the database block cannot be cleaned out immediately, it can potentially get cleaned out MUCH LATER - at which point Oracle may assign an ORA_ROWSCN much greater than X.  It has nothing to do with read consistency, dirty reads, or anything else you've accused me of being "deluded" about.  Or, just Google "ORA_ROWSCN block cleanout" for a number of good discussions, including more from Jonathan Lewis.

Comment: @SayanMalakshinov And it is not "easier" for me to illustrate a failure.  It would be if I had full access to my instance and didn't share it with anyone.   I'd need to be able to both flush the buffer cache and generate enough dummy activity to go through our (very large) undo tablespace to force a delayed block cleanout situation.  But I found this blog post that goes through most of it.  https://blog.fireheart.in/a?ID=00850-b55d9f8e-3128-47e0-95c1-7866758f18d7  The post doesn't use ROWDEPENDENCIES, but that doesn't change the effect.

Comment: @MatthewMcPeak of course, I did read it :) many years ago and I'll ask Jonathan a bit later with a show case of restoring dscn in the block. I'm not going to discuss his words here, since he talks about a bit different things, and it doesn't prove your words. Looks like I have to write an article about this explaining `dscn`...

Comment: @SayanMalakshinov The essence of what I am trying to explain to you is that if you do a really big update, Oracle will not/cannot update all the affected blocks to update them with the commit SCN.  Oracle will do that later, as part of a delayed block cleanout the next time the block is queried or updated.  If, at that time, the transaction slot and sequence of the committing transaction have been reused in the UNDO, then Oracle cannot assign an accurate ORA_ROWSCN during the delayed block cleanout.  And when that happens, any process using your solution for finding row will get wrong results.

Comment: And again, you don't need delayed commit cleanout, just force a flush of dirty blocks to disk using direct path reads

Answer (score 0):

Oracle does track how many inserts, updates, and deletes are performed on a table in the DBA_TAB_MODIFICATIONS view. It is not kept real-time so if you need to examine it over a small time period then you have to flush the stats so you can see (easily).

```
 execute dbms_stats.flush_database_monitoring_info;

-- Do work 

 select table_owner,table_name,inserts,updates,deletes from dba_tab_modifications  where table_name = 'RDS_LOG';

TABLE_OWNER                    TABLE_NAME                        INSERTS    UPDATES    DELETES
------------------------------ ------------------------------ ---------- ---------- ----------
MYUSER                         RDS_LOG                           4660111          0    1119531
```

Comment: How does this help *fetch latest 100 rows*?

Answer (score 0):

```
SQL> create table dt_del_ex(id number);

Table created.

SQL> set serveroutput on
SQL> BEGIN
  2
  3      INSERT INTO dt_del_ex VALUES(1);
  4
  5      DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line(TO_CHAR(SQL%ROWCOUNT)||' rows inserted');
  6
  7      INSERT INTO dt_del_ex select rownum from dual connect by level <=10;
  8
  9      DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line(TO_CHAR(SQL%ROWCOUNT)||' rows inserted');
 10
 11      UPDATE dt_del_ex SET id = id + 3 WHERE id >= 9;
 12
 13      DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line(TO_CHAR(SQL%ROWCOUNT)||' rows updated');
 14
 15      DELETE FROM dt_del_ex WHERE id <= 10;
 16
 17      DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line(TO_CHAR(SQL%ROWCOUNT)||' rows deleted');
 18
 19  END;
 20  /
1 rows inserted
10 rows inserted
2 rows updated
9 rows deleted
```

Comment: How does this help *fetch latest 100 rows*?